# React-Native, How to commit a modified package in node_module?

Tags: git, react-native, node-modules

I've modified a node module that is used in my app, but since all `node_module`s are in `.gitignore` I'm not able to commit the change to git repository.

How can I commit this particular file (not all node_modules files)?

Comment: you can't do that, But you can suggest your solution, if that issue is a common issue in that library, connect to the community and put your solution. then they will update the library. then you can get it. Otherwise there is no way to do that.

Comment: Better is update your `package.json` on remote so whenever you clone a repo. you  always going to have updated version of a package installed using npm. We never update a package on remote